# Print enum value using value converter without data binding

Tags: wpf, ivalueconverter

Let's say I have some enumeration, like:

```
enum MyEnum { value1, value2 }
```

and value converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(MyEnum), typeof(string))]
class MyEnumToString : IValueConverter
{
    ...
}
```

Now I want to print two `MyEnum` values converted using `MyEnumToString`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:MyEnumToString x:Key="myEnumToString"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<TextBlock Text="{here I want to print value1 converted by myEnumToString}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{here I want to print value2 converted by myEnumToString}"/>
```

How can I do this? Note that there is no data binding here, just two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Converter` used together with a *`Binding`*, quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `IValueConverter:` Provides a way to apply custom logic to a *`Binding`*.
>
> If you want to associate a value converter with a *`Binding`*, create a class that implements the `IValueConverter` interface and then implement the Convert and ConvertBack methods.

Therefore, you need to write this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=value1, Converter={StaticResource myEnumToString}}" ... />
```

If this values located in `ItemSource` or for root Control defined `DataContext`, try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myEnumToString}}" ... />
```

Either like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource myEnumToString}}" ... />
```

In this case, `Text="{Binding Path=.}"` is equivalent to `Text="{Binding}"`.

Comment: Well, I created static property for each enum value and bound to them from XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Like Anatoliy said you can't use a converter without a binding.

That's why a converter is used to convert the bound data if the bound data is updated.